# Is there a way to return documents which contain an array that is a subset of a given search array in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

Say I have a collection in Firestore which contains the following documents

```
{
name: foo
letters: [a, b, c]
}

{
name: bar
letters: [a, b, c, d, e]
}
```

And also have the following array which I want to use for the query

```
[a, b, c, d]
```

How can I query the collection so that it will return only the 'foo' document?

I initially thought I could use the `in` operator, but it matches for an exact match of array length, order, and values, so wouldn't work.

Comment: I guess you mean "How can I query the collection so that it will return only the 'bar' document?"

Comment: Is Renaud right? You need to get the bar document?

Comment: No I’m looking for a way to get only the ‘foo’ element. Sorry if the wording implied otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

There is no query operator in Firestore that returns only documents for which the `letters` field is a subset of the value you pass.

I'm wondering if you could get somewhere by concatenating all the array elements into two strings:

```
foo.letters_concat: 'abc'
bar.letters_concat: 'abcde'
search_concat: 'abcd'
```

But I admit that I don't immediately see how you could write the query even with those.

Given that, your only option is perform the filtering in the application code as far as I can tell.